# Upgrading MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I need to upgrade one of my servers, running mysql 5.7.  The DB and the OS is on different drives on my machine.

Can I drop the DB's from my 5.7 installation, reinstall the server with new OS and mysql 8.0, and then after the fact just reattach the DB's?

I have been running a mysqldump but it is very slow.

I am a mysql n00b btw.

Any advise will be appreciated.

Still trying to figure out what my steps are

Comment: Some additional Info: I have a second database running the same version 5.7 (replication DB).  I cant upgrade both databases on the separate servers at once.  My other plan is to reinstall the backup machine one and migrate from the main server.  From what I read, it seems that this can work from 5.7->8.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question whenever you need to add information, don't scatter question data in comments.

Comment: How big (GBs) is the dataset?  Are you writing to the database while migrating it?  If so, what will happen to the changes occurring during the migration?  There's no free lunch.

Comment: Before upgrading, I would highly suggest running checkForServerUpgrade() util using mysql-shell - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-upgrade.html. This will help determine if you need to do anything prior to the upgrade and will avoid a lot of headaches down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance so far.

To avoid any issues, I have reinstalled the OS with a blank MySQL DB and replicating it from my 5.7 DB to my 8.0 DB.

The replication is based on software specific configuration though for our monitoring system.